# Test results for ordered test are grouped in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server, ordered-test

I am running a few ordered tests using Azure DevOps pipelines. The result for the tests is grouped into a single ordered test. It is becoming very difficult to interpret the result. Is it possible to obtain a separate pass/fail result?

In the screenshot below, the ordered test contains about 75 tests and only one of them fails. But that results in an overall 1 Test failed result. Is it possible to show 74 passed, 1 failed result in the Tests Results?

[image: Test result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, since you are using ordered test. It's an expect behavior. The tests  will be grouped and be reported in a summarized view.

You could take a look at the statement in our official doc here-- [View summarized test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#view-summarized-test-results)

> During test execution, a test might spawn multiple instances or tests
>   that contribute to the overall outcome. Some examples are, tests that
>   are rerun, **tests composed of an ordered combination of other tests
>   (ordered tests)** or tests having different instances based on an
>   input parameter (data driven tests).
>
> As these tests are related, they must be reported together with the
>   overall outcome derived from the individual instances or tests.
>   **These test results are reported as a summarized test result in the Tests tab**:
>
> - Rerun failed tests: .......
> - Data driven tests: ...... The summarized view is also available for    ordered tests (.orderedtest in Visual Studio).

It's not possible to show 74 passed, 1 failed result in the Tests Results.

To see test results of individual tests in the ordered test suite you may need to download the `*.trx` file and open it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using the *.trx file to view the results on visual studio. Isn't it even possible to publish separated  result using the .trx file?

Comment: @ZankhanaRana Sorry, not sure about this. I haven't run into this scenario, you could give a try with using a sperate [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to check if this do the trick. If this also not work, afraid no way to handle it at the moment.

Comment: I followed the steps in the link you mentioned but no luck. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana Thanks for your quick update. Afraid this is a design limitation. You may have to keep using the *.trx file to view the results on visual studio to see pass test results. Apologize for any inconvenience. Besides, if my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer, which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Let me wait for some more time if there is any chance someone has come across the problem and has some solution to it. Otherwise I will mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get the individual results-

All the tests I wanted to run were in a single ordered test. I changed the build definition to run them individually and not as a part of a single ordered test. The only drawback of following this approach is we cannot rerun the failed tests.

[image: Test files]

Result:

[image: Results]